# Returning deleted rows from stored procedure in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a task that must be executed by MySql (v5.1.72) stored procedure. 
The task consists of several steps:

1. select rowset from one table by some condition
2. delete all rows, containing in rowset from step 1 (actually, delete rows by condition from step 1)
3. return from procedure rows, retrieved on step 1 (that were deleted on step 2)

And this procedure have some additional constraints:

1. it's expected to be invoked rather frequently, so there's a possible problem with creating temporary tables in request.
2. all data assigned to procedure call must be removed after procedure returned result and finished working. So, if result data is stored in table, this table must be automatically removed after procedure call.

Is it possible to solve this problem without additional tables?
And if not, how this can be done the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table that has a extra column name Guid, of type CHAR(38).

Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `TestId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Guid` char(38) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TestId`),
  KEY `Guid` (`Guid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The index `KEY Guid (Guid)` will help in the SP to faster process the data.

If you in your procedure define a golbal variable

```
DECLARE v_Guid CHAR(38);
```

Then you can set the value like this

```
SET v_Guid = SELECT UUID();
```

This would return a string like this `18d2e4ea-5d8c-11e3-b923-00ff90aef4a9`.

Now you can use this value `v_Guid` for every action that you make. `SELECT`, `INSERT` or `DELETE`.

When you later want to delete the rows. You just execute

```
DELETE FROM test_table WHERE Guid=v_Guid;
```

In this manner, the SP can use the same table even if the procedure runs and overlaps eachother. You never `DROP` the table, just delete the rows with the related `GUID`.

Have you considered someting like this?

Comment: Yes, i thought about something like this.
It works, but in my case source table is used by another functions, which rely on statement, that returned rows are not exist in the table. I need to fix them all to work correctly